# Input String was not in a correct form

Tags: c#, textbox

There are two text boxes called `unitprice.txt` and `quantity.txt`. there is another textbox called `total.txt` which keeps on getting updated as the when ever the user input unit price and quantity.

Oonce the user input these two those two textboxes are getting empty and total.txt getting updated by the total. it needs to be done continuously but in my code it is not and saying

`INPUT STRING WASN'T IN A CORRECT FORM.`

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;   
tot = int.Parse(unitprice.Text) * int.Parse(quantitytxt.Text);
sum = int.Parse(total.Text) + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

once the user enters the unit price and quantity total text boxe is updated by the toal. and again user enters the second item's unit price and quantity then previous value in total text box needs to be updated which means that new total generated from the second item needs to be added to previous total.(2500+3000=5500)

Hey it was solved but in this way.

```
int sum = 0;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    sum += int.Parse(qtytxt.Text) * int.Parse(unitprice.Text);
    total.Text = sum.ToString();    
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
}
```

Comment: What values you have in inputboxes?

Comment: integer values need to be entered

Comment: @user3505371 Question is what was the value in textbox at the time of exception?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel once the user enters the unit price and quantity total text boxe is updated by the toal. and again user enters the second item's unit price and quantity then previous value in total text box needs to be updated.

Comment: show your value in those textboxes

Comment: unit price is 100 qty is 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if text box value is not coming empty or not,If it is coming empty then set 0 as default while converting to parse Int otherwise it will show exception. see below code it will help you.

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;
tot = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(unitprice.Text.Trim()) ? "0" : unitprice.Text.Trim()) * int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantitytxt.Text.Trim()) ? "0" : quantitytxt.Text.Trim());
sum = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(total.Text.Trim()) ? "0" : total.Text.Trim()) + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a string value that is textbox value to integer, so you shouldn't do like the above, because may be it contains empty string or null value too. So, follow the below method of conversion, so that errors may not occur.

```
tot = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(unitprice.Text)) * Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(quantitytxt.Text));
```

Why you should follow the above method is, the `Convert.ToString()` will handle the null values and convert the null values to an Empty string and the `Convert.ToInt32()` will convert an empty string to 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another option, you can try Int32.TryParse(a_string_here, an_out_int_here);

For more, look at the documentation here:[MSDN TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It'll take a string and try to parse it to a valid int... if it fails, it returns 0.

```
int a ;

Int32.TryParse("5",out a);
System.Out.WriteLine("a="+a); // Will be: a=5

Int32.TryParse("e",out a);
System.Out.WriteLine("a="+a); // Will be: a=0
```

Answer (score 0):

`Int32.Parse()` will throw an exception if the input value is not an integer.  Use `Int32.TryParse()` to convert a value without throwing an exception.  If the conversion fails, `TryParse()` will return `false` and zero will be returned:

```
int intValue = -1;
bool result;
result = Int32.TryParse("23", out intValue); // result = true, intValue = 23
result = Int32.TryParse("AB", out intValue); // result = false, intValue = 0
```

EDIT: For your specific case, try this:

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;   
int price = 0;                           // output parameter to receive value
int quantity = 0;                        // output parameter to receive value
int total = 0;                           // output parameter to receive value
TryParse(unitprice.Text, out price);     // price contains the unit price value
TryParse(quantitytxt.Text out quantity); // quantity contains the quantity value
TryParse(total.Text, out total);         // total contains the total value
tot = price * quantity;
sum = total + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: @PeterGluck Thanks alot sir somehow it was solved but in a different way

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if text box value is not coming empty, as if you will parse it into Int and when its empty, there will be this or similar exception.

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;   
tot = int.Parse(unitprice.Text!=String.Empty?unitprice.Text:"0") * int.Parse(quantitytxt.Text!=String.Empty?quantitytxt.Text:"0");
sum = int.Parse(total.Text!=String.Empty?total.Text:"0") + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

You can also try:

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;   
tot = Convert.ToInt32(unitprice.Text!=String.Empty?unitprice.Text:"0") * Convert.ToInt32(quantitytxt.Text!=String.Empty?quantitytxt.Text:"0");
sum = Convert.ToInt32(total.Text!=String.Empty?total.Text:"0") + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: No those text boxes are not coming up with empty values we have to enter values in two textboxes

Comment: There is no problem with you code, please check if some additional comma or special character like dollar etc is not being entered.

Comment: No i have been checking this for hours now :(

Comment: Its working at my end with the values specified by you. Post some more code. UI as well as .cs file code.

Comment: you mean with the code i did or with the code you specified here?

Comment: can you please send me the cs file with the code that i mentioned if it is working ?my email is rohan123perera@gmail.com

Comment: but i don't understand why it is not working in my way. it should be working

Comment: Check mail and you can come to chat if you want to. No more comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0;   
tot = Convert.ToInt32(unitprice.Text.Replace(" ", "")) * Convert.ToInt32(quantitytxt.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
sum = Convert.ToInt32(total.Text.Replace(" ", "")) + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

If this throws an exception your textboxes probably has unwanted characters (i.e. commas: "1,000.00" or letters) or empty that makes the convertion throw an exception.

Comment: It'll be easier and (more than) probably more efficient to use `TryParse` instead of using the `Convert` with replacements ...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is...if the string is other than numbers ............

Any string value other than numbers will show an error saying INPUT STRING WASN'T IN A CORRECT FORM!!!.

there is a solution for this.....insert your code inside try catch  block

```
try{ your code here}catch(FormatException){}
```

or find another mechanism to avoid strings other than numbers....

Comment: i just enter like 2 for qty and 100 for unit price so nothing wrong with the values right?

Answer (score 0):

```
int tot = 0;
int sum = 0; 
tot = int.Parse(unitprice.Text+"0") * int.Parse(quantitytxt.Text+"0");
sum = int.Parse(total.Text+"0") + tot;
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Try this code.